# how can make XML layout compatible with all resoultion?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

[image]

its Ok with 720x1280 but when run it in 768x1280 not fit with screen so i try all ways like made layout-normal layout-small layout-large and ... but for example i want make this screen for normal-layout so problem is if i make this XML base on 720x1280 or 768x1280 ? or another screen 
subset layout-normal or another dpi subset layout-normal what can i do ? if i make this base on 768x1280 when run app in 720x1280 not fix and if make this base on 720x1280 when run app in 768x1280 not fix

so here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:background="@drawable/lastb"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="138dp"  />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:background="@drawable/qwe"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:background="@drawable/qwe"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:background="@drawable/qwe"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:background="@drawable/qwe"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bb"
            android:background="@drawable/df"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b2"
            android:layout_below="@id/b3"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:background="@drawable/qwe"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:background="@drawable/qwe"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bb"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/forward"
            android:background="@drawable/lastf"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b6"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="138dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Center-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/qwe" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/qwe" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/qwe" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/qwe" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/qwe" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/df" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/qwe" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your main relative layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

So, best way to fit all screen resolutions is to use **match_parent** for your layouts. In your case, you set **wrap_content** for RelativeLayout and you put views with specific width (android:layout_width="65dp") and layout will wrap around it so if you have big screens it will have space.

This is example how you can fill your screen horizontal with 4 buttons:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

With LinearLayout width set to match_parent, you will fit all screens sizes and setting for buttons **layout_weight="0.25** you are making button to take 25% of screen. Paste this code so you can get it how it works.

Comment: i try so many ways like this but problem is : when background Coming its become sophisticated . make button so easy but button or image button with background like mine so hard!